# Arrays containing 10 extra null elements when parsed into POJO with GSON

Tags: java, android, json, gson, pojo

I am receiving a Json object from web api,

it looks as follows:

```
{"Sites":[{"SiteId":1,"SiteName":"Site 1"},{"SiteId":2,"SiteName":"Site 2"},{"SiteId":3,"SiteName":"Site 3"}]}
```

Now I have the following code which uses gson to parse it to a POJO:

```
@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
    try {
        String json = new String(response.data,
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
        return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
    }
}
```

And here is my POJO:

```
 public class UsersSitesViewModel 
 {
     public List<UserSite> Sites;
 }

public class UserSite {

 public UserSite(int siteId, String siteName) 
 {
    SiteId = siteId;
    SiteName = siteName;
 }

 public int SiteId;
 public String SiteName;
}
```

But now when I run in my code and I debug to look at the pojo it created:

it looks as follows:

[image: View of instantiated POJO]

WHy is it inseting 10 Null values into my array?

That is incorrect!

Comment: so where is the issue?

Comment: Do you actually have 12 elements in the array when you parse it programmatically or there's only the 3 elements ? Maybe it's only the representation of the list that is faulty ?

Comment: @user3218114 The issue is the list it has creates has a whole bunch of null values in.,

Comment: @Nico The Json received is as it is shown in the question. There should only be 3 items in the list.

Comment: @Zapnologica No. [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) has an optimization on initialization to allocate extra entries for performance. If you call `size()` those aren't actually in use. Per the linked Javadoc, *Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are ...*

Comment: It does not. It's only for buffering, that means allocating memory. Alright so, don't worry. A debugger is a human like you an me :D

Comment: *WHy is it inseting 10 Null values into my array?* By default array initialize it's capacity to 12 to avoid frequent memory allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the ten null values is due to the way that Array Lists work. Array lists are essentially vectors, or things like act like arrays but automatically resize. To prevent extra amounts of copying memory around vectors (and ArrayLists) are generally created with additional memory. Since the time it takes to copy memory is larger than the time it takes to allocate memory at the beginning, most implementations just allocate extra space at the beginning.

We can tell that this is happening by the `size` attribute inside the ArrayList. The `size` is listed as `3`, which is the correct number of elements inside the array list. As such, when you query what the length of the array list is, you'll get `3`.

Comment: Do you have any reference from the official documentation about this behaviour ?

Comment: @Nico "Each ArrayList instance has a capacity. The capacity is the size of the array used to store the elements in the list. It is always at least as large as the list size. As elements are added to an ArrayList, its capacity grows automatically. The details of the growth policy are not specified beyond the fact that adding an element has constant amortized time cost." from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to Override `toString()` in `UserSite`,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
  return String.format("siteId = %d, siteName = %s", SiteId, SiteName);
}
```

Also, your fields should be `private`, and the Java naming convention would be `siteId` and `siteName`. By default, you inheret the [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) and per the Javadoc,

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine for me.

```
UsersSitesViewModel data = new Gson().fromJson(json, UsersSitesViewModel.class);
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data));
```

To follow the Java Naming convention use [`@SerializedName`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation

```
class UsersSitesViewModel {
    @SerializedName("Sites")
    private List<UserSite> sites;
    // getter & setter
}

class UserSite {

    @SerializedName("SiteId")
    private int siteId;
    @SerializedName("SiteName")
    private String siteName;
    // getter & setter
}
```

---

You can convert it into `Map<String,Object>` just for debugging purpose

```
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType();
Map<String, Object> data = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
```

output:

```
{
  "Sites": [
    {
      "SiteId": 1.0,
      "SiteName": "Site 1"
    },
    {
      "SiteId": 2.0,
      "SiteName": "Site 2"
    },
    {
      "SiteId": 3.0,
      "SiteName": "Site 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please see me question, I have added the exact code where it is deserialised. Its taken from the GsonRequest on the android site.

Comment: Also, I tried to add ` @SerializedName("Sites")` and eclipse is throwing an error. "Extract String"  and no import options...

Comment: `@SerializedName` is just to follow the java naming convention, that will never solve the issue. The issue is with the JSON string. Try last option.